# Ambiguity when calling overloaded function with vector as param

Tags: c++, c++20

I am writing a class in which I am overloading `operator[]` and I want one function to have vector as input and the second one to have vector of vectors as input, but when I call it like

```
obj[{ 0 }]
```

then I got ambigious call error. The functions are declared like

```
const Tensor operator[](const std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>>& ranges) const;
const float operator[](const std::vector<uint32_t>& index) const;
```

Is there any way to handle that ambiguity?

Comment: you can call it by explicitly calling the respective constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{0}` has no type. and it is valid to construct both `std::vector<uint32_t>` and `std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>>` (without overload resolution preference).

You might specify the type explicitly at call site:

```
obj[std::vector<uint32_t>{0}];
obj[std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>>{0}];
```

or add extra overload with higher priority:

```
Tensor operator[](const std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>>& ranges) const;
float operator[](const std::vector<uint32_t>& index) const;
float operator[](const std::initializer_list<uint32_t>& ini) const
{
    return operator[](std::vector(ini));
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6Ksn6E4qj)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler has no way of knowing by seeing the argument `{0}` which one to choose among the two equally ranked overloads.

One way to resolve the ambiguity is to explicitly tell the compiler as shown below:

```
obj[std::vector<uint32_t>{0}]; //calls #2
obj[std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>>{0}]; //calls #1
```

---

If you want to make it *more readable* you have the option of using `typedef` or `using` as shown below:

```
struct Tensor 
{
    //so that we don't have to type these again and again
    using vec = std::vector<uint32_t>;
    using vec2D = std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>>;
    
    //the two overloads here(below)
};
int main()
{
    Tensor obj;
    
    obj[Tensor::vec{0}]; //calls #2
    obj[Tensor::vec2D{0}]; //calls #1
    
}
```

Comment: Thank for you answer. However I was hoping for some other way, because that makes code look less simple.

Comment: @maciek97x You're welcome. Yes, the code does look less simple(or less readable) but that is what we've to do to resolve the ambiguity here. You can use `typedef` or `using` as shown in my updated answer. Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should always give the variables types in your code if they are not clear :

**Cast :**       `(type)variable`

**In your situation :** `const std::vector<uint32_t>&{vars}`

You should maybe make a typedef of this type to get more readable code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).